# Why is important to square returns?

Tags: return, time-series

I am studying log returns and I cannot understand why we should square the log returns to study autocorrelation. Can anyone clarify?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about computer programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree that it belongs on a different site such as math exchange (mathematics)